# Does a shared_ptr to a data member of an object keeps the data member alive past the life time of the object?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I have the following code skeleton. Is `pValue` still accessible past the life time of the `values` map ?

```
class Value { /* ... */ };
enum Key { aKey /* , ... */ };

class ValueStorage
{
public:
    ValueStorage() { /* calculate all kinds of values and store them */ }

    // returns nullptr if not available
    std::shared_ptr<Value> getValue(Key key)
    {
        auto it = values.find(key);
        return it != values.end() ? shared_ptr<Value>(&it->second) : nullptr;
    }
private:
    std::map<Key, Value> values;
};

shared_ptr<Value> pValue;
{
    ValueStorage values;
    pValue = getValue(aKey);
}
assert (pValue.get()); // is the Value the shared_ptr refers to still alive ?
```

In case it isn't, how could I avoid this problem ? Can I change something to the implementation of getValue ?

Or in case I cannot avoid the problem, should it be better to return a bare pointer to avoid confusion about its lifetime ?

(I could have avoided the hassle by just returning a value instead of a pointer, but I prefer the pointer version as it allows to return nullptr in case the value is not available)

Comment: No it does not. And you can get the optional return value behaviour with [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (and the not-quite-yet-standard [`std::experimental::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)).

Comment: How is `std::shared_ptr<Value> getValue(Key key);` implemented? The answer depends almost entirely on this.

Comment: @Niall I added a basic implementation. What could I do to the implementation to improve this ?

Comment: @mr_T. Ok, as in the answers, this is going to leave a pointer to a destroyed object and/or a deletion of an automatic (stack) value - either way you are going to run into all manner of trouble. Either return a reference to the map element, or construct a `shared_ptr` from a copy, or have as a value for the map a `std::shared_ptr<Value>` to begin with (thus there is always a shared ownership). Better still is to abstract what the client needs from the `value` interface of the`ValueStorage` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'll be a problem because you're constructing `std::shared_ptr<Value>` in `getValue()` based on the address of the element got from the map, when the map destroyed, all its elements will be destroyed either, then the pointer `shared_ptr` holding become dangled.

You might `new` a new pointer in `getValue()`, `shared_ptr` will `delete` it at last.

```
std::shared_ptr<Value> getValue(Key key)
{
    auto it = values.find(key);
    return it != values.end() ? shared_ptr<Value>(new Value(it->second)) : nullptr;
}
```

And don't return a bare pointer, the problem doesn't change at all.

Comment: Maybe the return statement can even be trimmed to return it != values.end() ? make_shared<Value>(it->second) : nullptr;

Answer (score 2):

A different approach would be to store `shared_ptr` inside your map:

```
std::map<Key, shared_ptr<Value>> values;
```

In this way, the function `getValue` will  invoke the copy constructor of shared_ptr, so increasing its counter.

Comment: This one sounds like the appropriate answer for the OP.  The OP wants the `Value` lifespan to outlive the map it may be contained in, so store the `shared_ptr<Value>` instead of just `Value`.

Answer (score 1):

Being able to return a "non-existent" handle is not a good reason for using a `shared_ptr`. As suggested in the comments, use `optional` for that, or return a bare (possibly null) pointer.

If for whatever reason you do need a `shared_ptr`, you need to think about ownership.

In this case all the `Value`s are owned by the `std::map`, which in turns is owned by the `ValueStorage`. That means `ValueStorage` must be alive as long as there is at least one `shared_ptr<Value>` around.

In order to achieve that, you want your `ValueStorage` life time to be managed by a `shared_ptr`, and `getValue` shall return a `shared_ptr` that uses the same control block as the `shared_ptr` that manages `ValueStorage`.

You can do that by using `enable_shared_from_this` and the constructor of `shared_ptr<T>` with the signature `shared_ptr( shared_ptr<U>, T* )`.

```
class ValueStorage : public std::enable_shared_from_this<ValueStorage>
{
public:
    ValueStorage() { /* calculate all kinds of values and store them */ }

    // returns nullptr if not available
    std::shared_ptr<Value> getValue(Key key)
    {
        auto it = values.find(key);
        if ( it == values.end() )
             return nullptr;

        // Return a shared_ptr that uses the same control block of
        // this ValueStorage
        // Note: this works as long as you do not invalidate "it", 
        // so you should not ever erase an element from the map.
        return shared_ptr<Value>(shared_from_this(), &it->second);
    }
private:
    std::map<Key, Value> values;
};

shared_ptr<Value> pValue;
{
    // ValueStorage needs to be managed by a shared_ptr.
    auto values = std::make_shared<ValueStorage>();

    // values can go out of scope
    // the ValueStorage will be kept alive as long as pValue is alive
    pValue = values->getValue(aKey);
}
```